# cloning melee combat from hollow knight

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im coding a platformer game and started cloning hollow knight to get inspiration and training. I'm investigating the behavior of the system during combat and I have some doubts and I'd like to get some help.

As for the hero:

1. Is there a cooldown between slashes or can you slash as fast as you want?
2. Is the hitbox of the slash bigger than the slash graphics?
3. When hit, you get this animation and you are invulnerable for a while. Can it happen that you land on an enemy after the animation and get automatically hit again??
4. when you hit something you get a small kick back too. Can you hit/be hit during this kick back ?

As for the enemies:

1. When hit.. do they "jump back"? I mean some kind of kick back animation that moves the enemy away from the hero. I think some do and some don't ..
2. When being kick back after an initial hit.. can they be hit again or they also get their invulnerable time?
3. and during this kick back moment can you be hit by them (by just touching them) or do their hit boxes get totally disabled?
4. can flaying monsters ignore platforms or they find you using something like A* ?

Comment: All these questions can be easily answered by simply launching and playing the game ?..

Comment: As it stands this is not a good question for StackOverflow, please narrow your question down to a specific problem you are encountering. Please take a look at the guidelines over here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you are trying to clone it, you need to sit and answer all the questions you have, its your project, we will happily help with specific coding issues but things that are opinions, questions about other software (eg how it works) are off scope for SO

Comment: I think you are going a bit over board saying that "if an enemy disables its hitbox after being hit" is an opinion. If you know the answer please enter it. If you don't pleas let others who know answer it.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting with the game itself and playing some videos in youtube frame by frame I thin that:

1. There is cooldown, you cannot slash as much as you click.
2. I would say that the hitbox of the sword is pretty accurate with its sprite
3. 4. When you hit something you receive a kick back, which is a surprise
      but yup, both you and the enemy get opposed kick backs that separate
      both of you. You get additional invulnerable time that allow you to
      move away from possible involuntary collisions.

As for the enemies:

1. The do get a kickback but the bigger foes do not.
2. Is hard to say because the kick back you get in your hero makes it hard to beat the enemy again. I've read that there is a badge that disables your kick back. So I understand they DONT have invulnerable time. Otherwise the badge would be useless.
3. since you get kick back you cannot be hit by them. Don't know what happen if you wear the badge.
4. Flaying monsters do collide with the platforms although I doubt they need something as sophisticated as A* but is unclear.